# String.Join format and adding a break line at end with a new set of data

Tags: c#

I have the following String.Join format within my foreach loop and I'm trying to insert a new line at the end of my DoneBy property. Unfortunately I get all my property formatted in one line. Please see my output bellow......

```
headerNames1.Add(ServiceAssistant.Tools.Language.Translate(Tools.Language.Keys.Done, ViewBag));
var headers1 = String.Join(",", headerNames1.ToArray());

sb.AppendLine(headers1);
foreach (var x1 in (List<StationHistoryReportResults>)TempData["excsv"])
{
    var data1 = String.Join(",", new string[] {
    //string.Format("\"{0}\"",item.B_Company),

    String.Join(",", x1.Activity.SelectMany( y => y.ProductsUsed).Select(z => z.ProductCode))?? string.Empty,
    String.Join(",", x1.Activity.SelectMany( y => y.ProductsUsed).Select(z => z.ProductTranslatedDescription))?? string.Empty,
    String.Join(",", x1.Activity.SelectMany( y => y.ProductsUsed).Select(z => z.Target))?? string.Empty,
    String.Join(",", x1.Activity.SelectMany( y => y.ProductsUsed).Select(z => z.DoneBy))?? string.Empty,
    });

    sb.AppendLine(data1);
}

csv = sb.ToString();
return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "StationExportData.csv");
```

[image: CSV OUTPUT]

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the raw text of the generated CSV, but my quick guess is that you're generating rows with unmatching columns; try changing those string.empty to a space

Comment: Please use an actual CSV library. Your solution is very fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an empty space after `sb.AppendLine(data1);`?

i.e.

```
sb.Append(" ");
```

or maybe

```
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
```